# WSO2 ESB Identity Server and Web Service Client

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I'm refering to the following article
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2010/10/using-xacml-fine-grained-authorization-wso2-platform/

I would like to use the sample `echoService` from the `WSO2 A`S over a secured proxy in `WSO2 ESB` in combination with the Identity Server for fine-grained authorization. All the settings mentioned on this page seem to work, however I am stuck concerning the client part. I use NetBeans and the given client code, but the .jars in the classpath there have older versions then the ones in the current version of WSO2 IS, so I started to exchange them manually. Now I get some exceptions like

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.init()V

and I am stuck again. I just want to test the `echoService` in this constellation and send some string over the ESB via IS and receive the response(if I have the appropriate role) from the AS, is there not another client or how could I test it else? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you 3 options:

1. Use SoapUI to test the service which is the easiest way to test a web service.
2. Generate the stub for the service and have stub as the dependency in your client. You can use the WSDL2Java tool that ship with AS. Loging to AS --> Tools in left pane --> WSDL2Java --> Provide the wsdl URL and generate the stub jar.
3. Generate correct dependency libs. Go to [IS-Home]/bin folder, and issue that command "ant" to run the build.xml, this will copy all required libs to [IS-HOME]/repository/lib/ folder. Have them in your class path.

Comment: I did your 3. suggestion and got some org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection refused  error, but I will figure it out somehow with my port and proxy settings. But your 1. suggestion SoapUI sounds interesting, I think I have to use java2wsdl in order to generate the necessary wsdl out of the code and use it in SoapUI,right? Thank you for your fast reply!